# how to bind from comma separated string to checkbox in gridview using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have table called Account like this,

```
ID   Code   X-Ref
1    1.1    NULL
2    1.2    NULL
3    1.3    NULL
...
```

I have binded Code values to dropdownlist, when i select code value in dropdown the gridview will display rest of the code values(i.e.,Except the one which i have selected in dropdownlist).

I have a checkbox in gridview when i select some of the row and click ok it will update the table with respect to code ID like as shown below,

```
ID   Code   X-Ref
1    1.1    1.2,1.3
2    1.2    1.1,1.3,1.4
3    1.3    1.2,1.4
...
```

Now the question is how to populate from database with checkbox enabled in gridview..
example..,
if i select 1.1 in drop down list the checkboxes of both row 1.2 and 1.3 should be checked in gridview. How to do that please help..

Comment: Use `String.Split` to get multiple `Codes` from your `X-Ref`-column. Then you can use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) to find all related records.

Comment: please help me with an example.., Thanks.

Comment: Example: [String.Split Method (Char())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it..

Comment: how do i make checkbox to be checked in gridview with respect to values in string i.e.,"1.2,1.3"

Comment: can you show your gridview code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick simple example, modify to your needs...

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim list As String = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
        list = list.Replace(" "c, String.Empty)
        Dim items As List(Of String) = list.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList
        For Each i As String In items
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```